# Asymptotic behavior of the integrand in a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, improper-integrals, stochastic-integrals, probability-limit-theorems

I am dealing with a stochastic integral (expected value) as follows: Suppose $c>0$, $X_t\ge0$ is an increasing process and $f\ge0$ is decreasing in $(-\infty,\infty)$. If
$$
E\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ct}|1-f(x+X_t)|dt\right)<\infty\;\;\mbox{for all}\;\;x,
$$
does it imply that there exists $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0)\le1$?

My argument is in the following:
Note that
$$
E\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ct}|1-f(x+X_t)|dt\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ct}|1-f(x+y)|dtP(X_t\in dy),
$$
which, by Fubini's theorem, equals to
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-ct}\int_{0}^{\infty}|1-f(x+y)|P(X_t\in dy)dt.
$$
Since the integral is convergent, $\lim_{y\to\infty}|1-f(x+y)|=0$. Hence, $x_0$ exists.

Any comment, help or clarification would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: 'Since the integral is convergent, $\lim_{y\to\infty}|1-f(x+y)|=0$': can you justify this?

Comment: I thought that the limit must be zero if the improper integral is convergent.

Comment: That is not correct. The integral converges even if the limit is $1$, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much.